# How to improve subscribe success, error callback?

Tags: angular

I have a lot of observable objects from request to the server. They are placed in different components and are not binded. It is single differ requests.

I subscribe each of them:

```
 obj1.subscribe(
                (response) => {
                    this.messageService.showMessage('', 'Success', 'success');
                 
                },
                () => {
                    this.messageService.showMessage('', 'Error', 'error');
                },
            );

 obj2.subscribe(
                (response) => {
                    this.messageService.showMessage('', 'Success', 'success');
                 
                },
                () => {
                    this.messageService.showMessage('', 'Error', 'error');
                },
            );
```

So, as you can see success/error callbask has duplication of code. How to avoid it and remove duplicates?

Yes, I can create the functions:

```
export const successResponse = () => {};
export const errorResponse = () => {};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing your work in subscribe, you could also do it in a pipe:

```
obj1
  .pipe(
     tap(value => <success code>),
     catchError(error => <error code>)
  );
```

The cool thing is that you can create a reusable pipe handler function:

```
import { pipe, of } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

const myPipeHandler = () => pipe(
     tap(value => <success code>),
     catchError(error => <error code>)
  )
```

You can then use the pipe like this in your observables:

```
obj1.pipe(myPipeHandler()).subscribe();
obj2.pipe(myPipeHandler()).subscribe();
```

Comment: tap() will always be executed for a normal observable emission, if an error is emitted, tap() will be skipped and catchError will be executed.
The only thing to consider is that an error you cause in tap, will also fall through to catchError then.

Comment: Why do you use pipe operator then pipe in function?

Comment: And how to pass message service to const myPipeHandler ?

Comment: Maybe `const observableHandler = () => of().pipe(`?

Comment: And `catchError` should return observer it mean I go to subscribe() anyway in error case

Comment: So if I got error I will see message and dialog will be closed. `subscribe(
                (response) => {
                    this.messageService.showMessage('', 'Success', 'success');
                    this.dialogRef.close(response);
                }` But it must work only in success response

Comment: You are probably missing some imports, I edited my answer. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can join your two observables

```
Observable.forkJoin([obj1, obj2]).subscribe(results => {
  // results[0] have the response of the first observable
  // results[1] have the response of the second observable

},
 () => {
     this.messageService.showMessage('', 'Error', 'error');
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant I have two observers in different components they are not binded